# How can i have a static collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections, discord, discord.js

so, im trying to do a backup system on Discord, with NodeJS, and my problem is, when i save the collection with all roles, when i modify a role on the server it also change the collection, that's weird. There is my code.

```js
// My index

const { Collection, Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

client.backup = new Collection();




// My command to set the collection

client.backup.set(message.guild.id, message.guild.roles.cache.array());




// My command to get the collection

const backup = client.backup.get(message.guild.id)

console.log(backup)
```

Okay so everything work fine, my command return the collection, but.. When i modify a role and i'm making again the command "to get" the collection and not to "set" it update the collection, and i don't know why.

Everytime i make

```js
client.backup.get(message.guild.id)
```

The collection update if i have modified something on the server, and i don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.array()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array) is cached internally and reconstructed on change.

Instead, write:

```js
client.backup.set(message.guild.id, Array.from(message.guild.roles.cache.values()));
```

Comment: It still changing, when i delete a role, it's also deleting it from the collection

Comment: @Lemaaa Well, you use your guild-id as key for the collection. So on each update the value at that key is overwritten.